# Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object

Tags: php, sql, database

I am not able to figure this out.  My website returns this error after I did the SQL 4 upgrade to 5.0

Unable to connect to database - Statement is null or not a SELECT 
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /main.php on line 28

Here is line that function:

```
//--Start DB Get this page Record  (pg_)---------------------------
$sql = new MySQLHandler();
 $sql->init();
 $this_page = $sql->Select("SELECT * FROM site_pages WHERE name='$page' LIMIT 1");
 while (list($key,$value) = each($this_page[0])) {
if (!is_int($key)) {
$solo = $this_page;
$solo = $solo[0][$key];
$key =  'pg_'.$key;
$$key =stripslashes($solo);
}
}
```

Line 28 is:  while (list($key,$value) = each($this_page[0])) {

Comment: The entire thing is explained by your first few words in the errors: **Unable to connect to database**.  How do you expect any SQL to work?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an error on your [MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/) installation (if your query used to work before you updated it), because you are receiving an `Unable to connect to database` error.

Comment: I fixed the database connection now I am still getting the error on line 28

Comment: I removed [page0] from $this_page[0] and the problem is solved.